# Display magento products from data recieved from web service

Tags: php, web-services, magento

I'm new to Magento CE 1.9. We need to display the list of products not from the database but from a XML received via a SAP web service.

Could someone please help me with the approach required for doing  this?

Answer (score 0):

**I THINK THIS IS WHAT U REQUIRE**

```
  public function ws_products($store_id, $service, $categoryid) 
  {
  $res=array();
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id); 
  $c_id = $categoryid;
  $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
  $category->load($c_id);
  $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addStoreFilter($store_id);
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  foreach ($collection as $_product) 
  {

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$taxClassId = $product->getData("tax_class_id");
$taxClasses = Mage::helper("core")->jsonDecode(Mage::helper("tax")->getAllRatesByProductClass());
$taxRate = $taxClasses["value_".$taxClassId];
$a = (($taxRate)/100) *  ($_product->getPrice());
                  $res[] = array(
                           "id" => $_product->getId(),
                           "name" => $_product->getName(),
                           "imageurl" => Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(),
                           "sku" => $_product->getSku(),
                           "spclprice" => number_format($_product->getSpecialprice(),2),
                           "price" => number_format($_product->getPrice(),2),
                           "tax" => number_format($a,2),
                           "created_date" => $_product->getCreatedAt(),
                           "is_in_stock" => $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock(),
                           "stock_quantity" => Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getId())->getQty()
                           ); 
     } 
     return($res); 
      }
```

HOPE THIS WILL HELP